# Python exceptions - a function with try...except clause in a loop

Tags: python, exception

I frequently encounter a situation like this:

```
import os

for i in range(10):
    os.mkdir(i)
```

However, sometimes a directory already exists, in which case os.mkdir throws an OSError. When this happens, I just want it to skip the rest of the loop and move to the next iteration of i, so I often write something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        os.mkdir(i)
    except OSError:
        continue
```

However, what I really, really want is a function which encapsulates that behaviour. Something like this:

```
def custom_mkdir(directory):
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
    except OSError:
        continue
```

So that I can have some code like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    custom_mkdir(i)
```

with the intended behaviour that it makes the directory if it doesn't exist but skips to the next interation of the for loop if it does.

However, the continue statement can't be included in a function in that way. So how do I get the intended behaviour without resorting to:

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        custom_mkdir(i)
    except OSError:
        continue
```

which is an even worse situation than the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if there's nothing else going on inside the loop you can just do this:

```
def custom_mkdir(directory):
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
    except OSError:
        pass

for i in range(10):
    custom_mkdir(i)
```

If there's actually more code below `custom_mkdir`, I think the best you can do is this:

```
def custom_mkdir(directory):
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False

for i in range(10):
    if not custom_mkdir(i):
       continue
```

or

```
for i in range(10):
    if custom_mkdir(i):
        # The rest of the logic in here
```

Which are at least a little more concise than the original.

Answer (score 2):

When `OSError` is caught inside `custom_mkdir`, what your function *really* wants to do is just do nothing.  So, do nothing:

```
def custom_mkdir(directory):
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
    except OSError:
        pass
```

Comment: That doesn't help the caller decide what to do though.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: Does the caller *need* to decide what to do?  In the code posted in the question, it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, the caller does. That's the point of the question. The OP wants to `continue` if the `mkdir` fails. They just want to encapsulate the try/except to make the loop look neater.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: But in the example code, `continue` is exactly the same as doing nothing.

Comment: The OP says, specifically, that they want to `continue`. You should assume there is more happening after the mkdir call, otherwise there'd be no point in `continuing` - and they'd just let the loop run out.

Comment: Yeah, the question is a little ambiguous. Based on the example, just using `pass` would work fine. But it would be strange for the OP to actually ask this question if `pass` actually *would* work fine for his/her use-case. I guess its possible he/she just doesn't know about or didn't think to use `pass`, though.

Comment: As dano correctly pointed out, pass works fine as long as there is no code after the try...except clause. But there is, and if I pass then it executes that code too, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Just return a bool:

```
def custom_mkdir(directory):
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)            
    except OSError:
        return False
    return True

for i in range(10):
    if not custom_mkdir(directory): continue
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
def cusyom_mkdir(diectory):
try:
    os.mkdir(directory)
    return True
except OSError:
    return False
```

status = map(cusyom_mkdir, [i for i in range(10)])

or

```
def cusyom_mkdir(diectory):
try:
    os.mkdir(directory)
    return True, directory
except OSError:
    return False, directory
```

status = map(cusyom_mkdir, [i for i in range(10)])

You can see that the directory is successfully created the directory creation fails